# Sharing image with EXPO

Tags: react-native, expo

I searched much , looks this process is not direct while using Expo

looks I need to download the file locally , then share it

```js
import {Share} from 'react-native';

const imageURL = "https://i.imgur.com/7RhCHg2.png";

const url = await downloadAsync(imageURL , cacheDirectory + "tmp.png");
            console.log(url); // it prints a local image file
            Share.share({url : url.uri , message : "Event Invitation" });
```

**The expected behavior**

the app should share the image plus the message "Event Invitation"

**The current behavior**

the app share only the message "Event Invitation" , it does not see the image or share it

Comment: follow this link. It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/75131356/14448694

Answer (score 0):

The content 'url' just work on iOS. If you want to share the image android, you can take a look this [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/)